# encoding pcm samples to mp3 in real time android, possible?

Tags: android, encoding, mp3, lame

I used LAME to encode wav to mp3 in android succesfuly. now i want to encode it in real time during the caputure of the pcm sample (meaning to pass the buffer insted of the file), is it possible using LAME to do it or i need to write new function for it?

http://lame.sourceforge.net/ - LAME